# Simulating connection errors with SQLAlchemy

Tags: unit-testing, sqlalchemy, database-connection

On production, my Flask / SQLAlchemy app randomly throws `psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly` on RDS Aurora. Until I track down the issue, I would like my unit tests to ensure that I handle this properly, e.g. that my rollback mechanism is effective, etc.

Right now, I mock the `Session.commit` method to throw a fake exception, but this does not (afaik?) leave the session in a failed state that needs actual rollback.

What are some reliable ways to simulate an actual connection failure in my local, Docker Compose-based development environment?

Comment: Did you have any luck finding a solutino to this @infojunkie?  I'm in the same boat.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I worked around this.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback with psycopg2

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    f"host='{credentials['host']}' port={credentials['port']} dbname='{credentials['dbname']}' user='{credentials['user']}' password='{credentials['password']}'"
)
print("Connected to database")
print("Setting autocommit false")
conn.autocommit = False

func_name= 'procedure_update_users'

print(f"Executing function {func_name}...")
try:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = f"""SELECT {func_name}();"""
    print(query)
    cur.execute(query)
    row = cur.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    print(f"Function {func_name} executed.")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    conn.rollback()
    raise Exception(e)
```

To get OperationalError I did:

```py
try:
    cur.execute("LOCK TABLE mytable IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT")
except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
    cur.execute("rollback")
    raise Exception(e)
```

> psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this simulates a connection error.